# Why NFC feature is still required even I declare the android:required="false" attribute?

Tags: android, uses-feature

I write the NFC related declaration in the AndroidManifest like below:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc.hce" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
```

I hope in this way, google play will not filter my app in the phone without NFC function. But unfortunately, I checked the installed app, found the NFC is still required....just don't know why

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
try {
    PackageInfo packageInfo1 = pm.getPackageInfo("My pakcage name", PackageManager.GET_CONFIGURATIONS);
    if(packageInfo1 != null && packageInfo1.reqFeatures != null) {
        for(FeatureInfo featureInfo : packageInfo1.reqFeatures) {
            Log.d("TAG", "name:"+featureInfo.name + ", flag:" + featureInfo.flags+",version:"+featureInfo.version);
        }
    }
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The output:

> ```
> 03-15 12:21:56.673 17052-17052/mapbox1.myapplication D/TAG: name:android.hardware.nfc.hce, flag:1,version:0
> ```

### The flag in the FeatureInfo is 1, which means required....

I paste my Manifest below, removing activities and services, etc:
[image]

And the full output:

> 03-15 12:41:02.982 17052-17052/mapbox1.myapplication D/TAG: name:android.hardware.bluetooth_le, flag:1,version:0
>
> 03-15 12:41:02.982 17052-17052/mapbox1.myapplication D/TAG: name:android.hardware.nfc.hce, flag:1,version:0
>
> 03-15 12:41:02.982 17052-17052/mapbox1.myapplication D/TAG: name:android.hardware.camera, flag:1,version:0
>
> 03-15 12:41:02.982 17052-17052/mapbox1.myapplication D/TAG: name:android.hardware.camera.autofocus, flag:0,version:0

The `required=false` in autofocus worked as desired, but NFC's required attribute not working. (`android.hardware.camera`'s required not working, probably because of the `android.permission.CAMERA`)

Comment: From: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions It looks like feature `android.hardware.nfc.hce` is deprecated. Just try with `android.hardware.nfc`

Answer (score 1):

I suspect there are the 3rd libraries overriding this, so I just add the *tools:replace="android:required"* to use the App's *android:required="false"*. This solves my problem